# How do I extract the value of a UIInput in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have an Xpages application that manipulates Contracts.  One procedure uses the Contract Type value in field "conService" to determine what must happen next.  The code below does **NOT** produce any errors but third line does not seem to process any result and in fact does not even seem to process any line in the procedure after it.  How do I extract the value of the conService?  Thanks

```
UIInput uifield = (UIInput) JSFUtil.findComponent("conService");
String serviceName ="";
serviceName = uifield.getValue().toString();
```

Comment: Have you verified that uifield points to the object? If you sysout uifield.toString(), does it return null or a pointer to the object? Alternatively, you can sysout any property that returns a string just so you know your first line here is working.

Comment: Steve - thanks everyone has been helpful so far with this.  I did as you said and the System output was astonishing because it was not NULL but also not what I thought the output would be.  Is this output a pointer to the object and if so I take it I have to do some more manipulation?  UIFIELD OutPut: com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspSelectOneMenu@43474347

Comment: You got what I would expect.  Mainly that tells me that you did in the first line worked and you did get a reference to the object.  Looks like you got some good answers below.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there....

Once you have the UIInput object you can do either .getSubmittedValue() or .getValue() - depending on where in the JSF lifecycle you are. And then you just need to cast it to a String  - instead of using toString().

So something like should do the trick:

```
UIInput uifield = (UIInput) JSFUtil.findComponent("conService");
String serviceName = (String)uifield.getValue();
```

To avoid having to thinkg about using getSubmittedValue or getValue I use a small utility method in my code:

```
ublic static Object getSubmittedValue(UIComponent c) {
    // value submitted from the browser
    Object o = null;
    if (null != c) {
        o = ((UIInput) c).getSubmittedValue();
        if (null == o) {
            // else not yet submitted
            o = ((UIInput) c).getValue();
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

That just makes life a little less complicated ;-)

/John

Comment: Thanks John.  This has assisted so far and now I have "a" value being retrieved but appears to state "null", however, as I replied to Steve above the output from UIInput uifield = (UIInput) JSFUtil.findComponent("conService");
  System.out.println("UIFIELD OutPut: " + uifield.toString()); is 
UIFIELD OutPut: com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspSelectOneMenu@43474347 - which may be a pointer to an object.  Note: I did not create this application and it is overly complicated.

Comment: Ahhh..... From what you write the field is NOT an input field.... The code I showed you works for input fields (I use it quite a lot in validators to obtain values from other components during validation). You may need to show is your markup and tell us where the Java code is called?

Comment: ... forgot to mention - if you refer to the component after JSF phase 4 then you should "talk" directly to the model (this is where I normally use a bean and can talk directly to the values through setters/getters on the bean. I have a simple demo database that shows some of the use in validators (among other things) - you can get it from: https://bitbucket.org/john_dalsgaard/demo-apps. There are some issues in this app. at the moment re preloading - but it can show you uses of component binding in validators (thanks to Tim Tripcony's video on component binding #codefortim)

Answer (score 2):

Where possible, it's worth going directly to the datasource you're storing the value in. It's more efficient and easier to manage.

If you do need the value during Process Validation phase, for a converter or validator, you can use component binding to easily access the relevant component, at which point you can use getSubmittedValue() - because the value will not have been set yet. Here's a NotesIn9 from Tim Tripcony covering it http://notesin9.com/index.php/2014/05/22/notesin9-143-component-vs-value-binding-in-xpages/.